# open an specific excel sheet from powerpoint using object

Tags: excel, powerpoint

Im trying to open a specific excel sheet from my PPt-slide using "insert>>object".
So my Excel Workbook is calling " mape1", and in this Workbook here are many sheets, and I want to open a specific one called "sheet1".

I gave the following pfad in the "object"

As Example

**C:\Users\me\Desktop\mappe1\sheet1.xls**

But it doesn't work
what am I missing?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check out this support article from Microsoft I've linked below.  It says by using the insert method you will bring in "all data from the active, top spreadsheet in the linked Excel workbook."

I suggest copy and pasting the selection you want into PowerPoint as is described here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-Excel-into-PowerPoint-3ec295e9-1bfd-47ff-8d7d-8b838caef853#__toc241650191